# Repair accents on php with htmlentities

Tags: php

i want repair the problem of accents , but I have this

> error Warning: htmlentities() expects parameter 2 to be long, string
>   given in

my code :

```
function check_and_secure($T, $field)
{
    if (!isSet($T[$field]))
        return "";
        $in_utf8encoded="é à ù è ò";
       $in_iso8859encoded=iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1",$in_utf8encoded);
 return   $out_iso8859= htmlentities($T[$field],$in_iso8859encoded, ENT_COMPAT, "ISO-8859-1");

}
```

Comment: The error is correct - the second parameter is supposed to be a long, specifically one defined by a constant.  You should read the docs on the function for more info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is where the error lies, and should also fix your problem

> code

```
<?php

function check_and_secure($T, $field)
{
    if (isSet($T[$field])) {
       $in_iso8859encoded=iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1",$T[$field]);
       return htmlentities($in_iso8859encoded, ENT_COMPAT, "ISO-8859-1");
    }
    return "";
}

echo check_and_secure(['a' => "é à ù è ò"], 'a');
```

> output

```
&eacute; &agrave; &ugrave; &egrave; &ograve;
```

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? You can get this from doing `echo PHP_VERSION;`

Comment: did you run my code exactly as provided, or did you make modifications or pass in a different string? If you passed in a different string what was it?

Answer (score 0):

I have at last managed with this code :

```
function check_and_secure($T, $field)
{
    if (!isSet($T[$field]))
        return "";
    return (html_entity_decode($T[$field]));
}
```

Comment: this is the complete opposite function then you were trying to use. it will take `&eacute;` and make it `é`